# Docker Swarm Service Discovery in index.html

Tags: docker, containers

I have two express web apps (`server` and `client`) that I am using `docker-compose` and / or `docker stack` to deploy in docker swarm. They both have APIs that communicate with each other via their service names, as they are both connected to the same overlay network. A snippet of the config file that `client` uses to make REST calls to `server` follows:

```
"server": {
  "url":"http://server:8085",
  "endpoints": {
    "devices": "/devices",
    "temperature": "/temperature",
    "mock": "/mock"
  }
}
```

Finding the server by host name is no issue from the node side as it is running directly inside the docker container. However, both express apps serve web pages. Both `client` and `server`'s css and js dependencies are almost identical and I do not want to write each stylesheet twice. I'd rather server a single copy from `server` that both `index.html` files from `server` and `client` can use.

In the `index.html`, of `server` I can use relative paths because the host is the same, and thus implied. But, in `index.html` of `client` I need a fully qualified url. Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://server:8085/style.css">
```

Obviously this would not work once I serve `index.html` from `client` to a browser because the browser is going to look for `http://server` over the internet, rather than in the docker overlay network for these services.

I thought about downloading the files in `client`'s node app before it serves `index.html` but, that's not the cleanest solution.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this without binding `server` to a static ip / domain or programmatically downloading these files first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your external users' browser needs to access files on `client` and `server` then you will need to publish both Swarm Services to the external IP's of the Swarm nodes, and then put those IP's in DNS names or an external LB, and only use those URL's for remote connectivity.

When you do that, you'll likely need to bind both services to the same port (443). If that's the case, then you also need another layer of proxy that routes traffic to the proper container based on path or DNS name.

Both http://proxy.dockerflow.com/ and https://traefik.io/ work for that purpose.

Comment: What does "LB" refer to?

Comment: load balancer. haha. This makes sense. Thank you. I didn't know tools such as traefik existed. Thanks!